# I am new in magento! :: I have task to add a custom field('is_vip') in order columns. please help me?

Tags: sales-order, sales, order-grid, sales-quote, sales-rule

Programatically, add a custom field('is_vip') in order. If a customer order value over $150 , the field value will be 1 and in order grid it will show yes.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new custom field is not a good idea for this situation.

Using PHP function will be more simple and have good maintenance.

```
<?php

class someclass {

  public function isVip($order)
  {
    return 150.0 >= (float)$order->getGrandTotal();
  }
}
```

If you still want to store `is_vip` in `sales_order` table.

You can use [`db_schema.xml`](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/configuration/) to add a new column.

And when creating and updating sales_order to update the new filed.